# Google Sheets: ArrayFormula with CountBlank

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to wrap the following formula in an array formula:

```
=IF(A3=0,,COUNTBLANK(E3:3))
```

I tried doing this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A=0,,COUNTBLANK(E3:E:3)))
```

but get a formula error.

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((LEN(A3:A))*(A3:A<>0), COLUMNS(E3:3)-
 MMULT(IFERROR(LEN(INDIRECT("E3:"&ADDRESS(ROWS(A1:A),
 COLUMNS(A1:1),4)))/LEN(INDIRECT("E3:"&ADDRESS(ROWS(A1:A),
 COLUMNS(A1:1),4))), 0), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(E3:3)^0)), ))
```

[image: 0]